# DataScannerViewController does not work on visionOS

Tags: swift, visionos, visionkit

i just started to test the DataScannerViewController on my Apple Vision Pro.
The documentation says that it is available for vision OS 1.0+ (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/visionkit/datascannerviewcontroller), but if i start the Sample Code from here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/visionkit/scanning-data-with-the-camera. The Log says it is not supported.

Does anyone know whats going on?

```
@MainActor
struct DocumentScannerView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: DataScannerViewController, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
    
    var scannerViewController: DataScannerViewController = DataScannerViewController(
        recognizedDataTypes: [.text(), .barcode()],
        qualityLevel: .accurate,
        recognizesMultipleItems: false,
        isHighFrameRateTrackingEnabled: false,
        isHighlightingEnabled: true
    )
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> DataScannerViewController {
        scannerViewController.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        // Add a button to start scanning
        let scanButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        scanButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBlue
        scanButton.setTitle("Start Scan", for: .normal)
        scanButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        scanButton.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.startScanning(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        scannerViewController.view.addSubview(scanButton)
        
        // Set up button constraints
        scanButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scanButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scannerViewController.view.centerXAnchor),
            scanButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scannerViewController.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -20)
        ])
        
        return scannerViewController
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }

    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, DataScannerViewControllerDelegate {
        var parent: DocumentScannerView
        var roundBoxMappings: [UUID: UIView] = [:]
        
        init(_ parent: DocumentScannerView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        // DataScannerViewControllerDelegate - methods starts here
        func dataScanner(_ dataScanner: DataScannerViewController, didAdd addedItems: [RecognizedItem], allItems: [RecognizedItem]) {
            //ToDo
        }
        
        func dataScanner(_ dataScanner: DataScannerViewController, didRemove removedItems: [RecognizedItem], allItems: [RecognizedItem]) {
            //ToDo
        }
        
        func dataScanner(_ dataScanner: DataScannerViewController, didUpdate updatedItems: [RecognizedItem], allItems: [RecognizedItem]) {
            //ToDo
        }
        
        func dataScanner(_ dataScanner: DataScannerViewController, didTapOn item: RecognizedItem) {
            //ToDo
        }
        // DataScannerViewControllerDelegate - methods ends here
        
        // Add this method to start scanning
        @objc func startScanning(_ sender: UIButton) {
            do {
                try parent.scannerViewController.startScanning()
            } catch let error {
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apple has provided a compatibility list [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/visionos/checking-whether-your-app-is-compatible-with-visionos)

> The following features aren’t available in compatible iPad and iPhone apps in visionOS. Use framework APIs to determine when the features are available.
>
> Video or still-photo capture

> Camera features like auto-focus or flash

> Rear-facing (selfie) cameras

> **Vision. Data scanners do nothing in VisionKit.**

For this particular ViewController you can use to confirm compatibility.

```
if DataScannerViewController.isSupported && DataScannerViewController.isAvailable{
    // Available
} else {
    // Show error, visionOS will enter here because while it is available it is not supported.
}
```

The "Notes" app uses the iPhone to scan the document and then passes it on to the VisionPro via iCloud.

Comment: Tank you for your answer. What you describe with the Note app is the VNDocumentCameraViewController (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/visionkit/vndocumentcameraviewcontroller) and for that apple provide a workaround like you described. What i am asking for is the DataScannerViewController and the feature to scan in a live camera feed data from any objects. This component is available in the SDK for vision OS (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/visionkit/datascannerviewcontroller) but the isSupported Flag is always false for vision OS. That is funny. 

Thanks!

Comment: @user14590906 Apple says that the data scanner doesn’t to anything. It is all in my answer.